# PCs losing connection to server

Tags: windows-server-2003, connection, lost

I'm going to try my best to describe the problem since I'm not the SysAdmin!

At my office, we have multiple PCs who connect to a Microsoft Server 2003 - Entreprise Edition.

We didn't do any modification to the server, but for some reasons PCs have problems holding a connection with it. Even tho the server is managing the loggings, they stay connected. When they lose connection, i feel like it's just for about a second, and then it goes back on. For exemple : they connect to the server, see their documents, browse, and when say open something, it hangs. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

I don't know what kind of information you guys needs, so just let me know if I can help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a network bottleneck to me. I've seen behavior like this when a process is bogging down the network with a big load (ie backing up to an iscsi drive using the same router as the rest of the network).

Do you have any way to monitor the traffic your network / router is receiving at any given time? I would also advise checking the load (and speed) of the NIC on the server you're describing as there may be an issue with the hardware there. I've seen a bad cable screw up the auto-negotiate speed and set it to 10/100 instead of 10/100/1000 Mbps before so take that into consideration as well.

Comment: I have the "Microsoft Network Monitor" in the Administrative Tools, but that's really unclear to me

Comment: If the network monitor is above your skill set then you can also go into the task manager (ctrl+alt+del) and click on the networking tab. This isn't a fool proof method but it will give you an idea at how much traffic your server NIC is seeing. I would take a look at your router / switch first though because the problem may exist on your whole network but your users only notice it when they interact with the server.

Comment: Showed your answer to the sysadmin, seems like there is a problem with  the network card (from what he said). Thanks for the info! :)